# AWS Lambda function for AWS Metric using Autoscaling groups

Tags: python, lambda, aws-lambda, boto3

I am in the midst of coding a lambda function which will create an alarm based upon some disk metrics. The code so far looks like this:

```
import collections
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    alarm = client.put_metric_alarm(
    AlarmName='Disk Monitor',
    MetricName='disk_used_percent',
    Namespace='CWAgent',
    Statistic='Maximum',
    ComparisonOperator='GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold',
    Threshold=60.0,
    Period=10,
    EvaluationPeriods=3,
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'InstanceId',
            'Value': '{instance_id}'
        },
        {
            'Name': 'AutoScalingGroupName',
            'Value': '{instance_id}'
        },
        {
            'Name': 'fstype',
            'Value': 'xfs'
        },
        {
            'Name': 'path',
            'Value': '/'
        }
    ],
    Unit='Percent',
    ActionsEnabled=True)
```

As seen, `{instance_id}` is a variable because the idea is that this will be used for every instance. However, I am wondering how I would code the same for `AutoScalingGroupName` because I require this to be a variable also. I know that that the below pulls out the `AutoScalingGroupName` for me, but how would I add that to the above block in terms of syntax, is my problem:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --output text --query "AutoScalingInstances[?InstanceId == '<instance_dets>'].{AutoScalingGroupName:AutoScalingGroupName}"
```

For example, would I add a block beginning as below:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
```

And if so, how would I then code what is needed in terms of syntax to get the `'Value': '{AutoScalingGroupName}'` by which I mean a variable to hold the ASG?

Comment: Where do `instance_id` and `asg_name` variable come from?

Comment: They are global variables set at a system wide level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[describe_auto_scaling_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.describe_auto_scaling_instances) takes `InstanceIds` as a parameter. So if you know your `instance_id` you can find its asg as follows:

```
client = boto3.client('autoscaling')

response = client.describe_auto_scaling_instances(
    InstanceIds=[instance_id])

asg_name = ''

if response['AutoScalingInstances']:
  asg_name = response['AutoScalingInstances'][0]['AutoScalingGroupName']

print(asg_name)
```